# Build a list with abs() in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am attempting to write a predicate for the following task.

Write a predicate distances(Bs, B, Ds) where Bs and Ds are lists of variables such that
the ith element of the Ds is the absolute difference between the variable B and the ith element of Bs

know this is incorrect but it what I believe I roughly should be trying to do

```
distances([],_,[]).
distances([H|T],B,A) :-abs(H - B,A),distances(T,B,A)
```

Do I need to return the result of the abs predicate into the recusive call to distance?

I can use abs to calculate the correct value for each entry in the list but how do I then put that information into a list which can then  be returned?

Comment: `s/[]/_/` in the fact's third argument

Comment: There is no `abs/2` standard predicate but there is a standard `abs/1` arithmetic function. Write instead `A is abs(H-B)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A predicate does not *return*. A predicate succeeds, fails, (gets stuck in an infinite loop, or raises an error). One uses unification to provide results. In fact here your third parameters `Ds` should probably provide the result.

We thus can unify the absolute value `D` to the head of the list of the third parameter, and recurse on the tail `Ds`:

```
distances([], _, []).
distances([H|T], B, [D|Ds]) :-
    abs(H - B, D),
    distances(T, B, Ds).
```