# Prolog - Using append to return a single list

Tags: prolog

Write a predicate triangle(Bs, Ds) where Bs a list of the positions of the foo and Ds is the (single) list of differences in position. Use the built-in predicate append and the your own distances predicate.

This is related to this questions :
[Build a list with abs() in prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60979954/build-a-list-with-abs-in-prolog)

```
distances([], _, []).
distances([H|T], B, [D|Ds]) :- abs(H - B, D), distances(T, B, Ds).

triangle([],[]).
triangle([H|T], [D|Dt]) :-  distances(T,H,D), triangle(T,Dt).


?- triangle([1,2,3],A).
A = [[1, 2], [1], []].
```

The Solution I require

```
?- triangle([1,2,3],A).
A = [1,2,1].
```

The answer is correct but it is a in list of lists.

I'm having trouble turning Ds into a single list. I have tried using append in various positions within the predicate but either get repetitions or the predicate evaluates to false. How can I turn Ds into a single list [1,2,3] with append?

Comment: So the solution should be `[1,2,1]`?

Comment: Yes [1,2,1] that is the correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append the list `D` with `Dt`, instead of using `[D|Dt]` where you thus prepend the list with one element `D`:

```
triangle([],[]).
triangle([H|T], Ds) :-
    distances(T, H, D),
    append(D, Dt, Ds),
    triangle(T, Dt).
```